# R Function Find First Non-True in data frame

Tags: r, function, loops, apply

I'm trying to find the first non-True (minus 1) for each row in a data frame.

The result looks like this:

```
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5 true
1  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE    1
2  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA    1
3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE    0
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    0
5 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    0
6 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    0
```

The following code works, but takes too long due to looping. I'm not sure how to properly execute this using an apply statement.

```
#Create the function to find the first non-true
min.true <- function(x,i){
min(which(x[i,]==!TRUE))-1
}

#Create a null column
match.words$true <- NA

#Find the first non true in each row
for (i in 1:nrow(match.words)){
match.words$true[i] <-  min.true(match.words,i)  

}
```

Essentially I'm looking for something like this that would run faster

```
match.words$true <- apply(match.words, 1, min.true(match.words))
```

Comment: Not sure what that's about. . . Did you post without sample data initially? Perhaps they wanted data they could copy and paste. Anyways, hope my answer is helpful.

Comment: I'm a little confused myself, the R community here generally downvotes in a pretty targeted manner.

Comment: Is each row guaranteed to have at least one TRUE?

Comment: Sorry, should have posted sample data, but I thought the table above would work.

Comment: There is no guarantee that a TRUE will occur

Comment: Sorry, I asked backwards. Is there the possibility of all TRUE?

Comment: No, that that will not occur either. Essentially I'm creating a function to find the longest common starting substring. I have two lists. List A with 400 companies. List B with 100,000 companies. To do this, I'm breaking up each company in List A to individual letters and then comparing them to each company in List B. The first FALSE or NA tells me how long the common starting substring is.

Comment: `which(x[i, ] == !TRUE)` seems really convoluted. `!TRUE` is the same as `FALSE`, and `== FALSE` is equivalent to `!`, so I think it could just be `which(!x[i, ])`.

Answer (score 4):

A simple variant in base R:

```
match.words$true <- apply(match.words, 1, which.min) - 1
```

The function `which.min(x)`
returns the index of the minimum value in a vector `x` or, in the case of a logic vector, the index of the first `FALSE` value. This is described in the help page of `?which.min`:

> Where is the Min() or Max() or first TRUE or FALSE ?
>
> Description
>
> Determines the location, i.e., index of the (first) minimum or maximum of a numeric (or logical) vector.

Therefore the output of `which.min()` is exactly what we need in this case. All that is left to do is to wrap that into `apply()` with margin 1 to obtain the index for each row and subtract `1`, as requested in the problem statement.

---

**Edit:**

A special case occurs if the data.frame constains rows where *all* values are `TRUE`. Then, `which.min()` returns the first index of these rows, which may not be appropriate here. Since no `FALSE` value is found, it may be better to return `NA` instead. If such a situation occurs one can identify the relevant rows before creating the match.words$true column:

```
NArows <- which(apply(df1, 1, all))
match.words$true <- apply(match.words, 1, which.min) - 1
match.words$true[NArows] <- NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Some data like yours:

```
t <- matrix(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE,
              FALSE, FALSE, NA), nrow=2)
t
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE    NA
```

Slightly modified function:

```
min.true <- function(x){
  min(which(x==!TRUE))-1
}
```

Test it on one row:

```
min.true(t[1,])
# [1] 1
```

Apply it to each row:

```
apply(t, 1, min.true)
# [1] 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, perfect. I spent an hour trying to research this, Don't get all the negative reps at this site.

Comment: This particular version will fail if you have all TRUE values in a row (well, it will return Inf with a warning).

Comment: ahh, I gotcha, now, ya there are some rows with All TRUES & NA (i.e. no false) and it does return INF. But I think that just means exact match for my particular data, which is ok.

Answer (score 2):

`?max.col` can be adapted to work here, which should be relatively quick. Using @TARehman's `data_mat` renamed as `mat` for simplicity here:

```
tmp <- replace(!mat, is.na(mat), FALSE)
replace(max.col(tmp,"first")-1, rowSums(tmp)==0, NA)
#[1]  1  1  0 NA  0  0 NA  3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
match.words$true = apply(match.words,MARGIN = 1,function(t){return(min(which(t!=T))-1)})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option which works using a different mechanism, the `rle` function. It has the benefit of needing little in the way of input sanitization.

```
data_mat <- matrix(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE,
                     TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, 
                     FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
                     TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,
                     FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,
                     FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
                     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                     NA, NA, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), nrow=8, byrow = TRUE)

func_first_nontrue_row <- function(input_row) {

    row <- rle(input_row)
    first_nontrue <- head(x = head(x = cumsum(c(1,row$lengths)),n = -1)[which(!row$values)],
                          n = 1) - 1
    if(length(first_nontrue) == 0) {return(-99)} else {return(first_nontrue)}
}

output <- apply(X = data_mat,MARGIN = 1,FUN = func_first_true_row)
output
## [1]   1   1   0 -99   0   0 -99   3
```

EDITED TO FIX AND EXPLAIN:
The `rle` function creates an object which encodes the lengths of runs of data in a vector (hence `rle` for run-length encoding).

By taking the cumulative sum of a vector consisting of 1 and the `lengths` (the start point, plus the length of each item), and then dropping the last element, you get the start position of each run. Using the `values` argument, you can subset that vector to only the FALSE statements. So, a call to `head()` to grab the first, and a prior call to `head()` to drop the last element. I sanitized it so that there was a check for rows that have zero FALSE statements, by simply checking that the output has a length that isn't 0. You could tweak it as you needed.

Speedwise, I'm not sure this will be better than other solutions, but it has the benefit of always producing something, since the `rle` call will always create actual values to work on, even if fed an entire vector of NAs.